# How to provide a system of input every x time interval (e.g, x=1 week)

Tags: differential-equations

The following code described an input to the system only during t less than minInfusionTime after time zero.  Any way to give this same input every x time (e.g. every week) after time of zero, to an ODE system A[t]? In another word, the system receive an input every week, with an input rate of (mgDose/minInfusionTime)

```
mgDose = 50;
minInfusionTime = 15;
inputSignal = 
  Function[t, 
   Piecewise[{{mgDose/minInfusionTime, t < minInfusionTime}}, 0]];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Math Entry! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `If` and `Mod` inside `NDSolve` to achieve this.  Here I assume time is measured in hours and there are first-order decay kinetics.

```
mgDose = 50;
minInfusionTime = 15;
τ = 7*24; (* period *)
tmax = 5 τ;
l = 0.001;

sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] ==
  If[0 < Mod[t, τ] < minInfusionTime, mgDose/minInfusionTime, 0] - l a[t],
  a[0] == 0}, a, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

Plot[a[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you!  Besides Mod, any other approaches?

Comment: If you are OK with an impulsive input instead of one distributed over the finite time `minInfusionTime`, you could use `WhenEvent` inside the `NDSolve`.